# Whats the difference between `UIControlState()` and `UIControlState.normal` when configuring an object

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I usually seen `UIControlState.normal` used, for example to set a `titleColor` on a `UIButton` object that will be used among all control states, as the `UIButton. setTitleColor` docs says:

> In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is
>   to use the normal value. If the normal value is not set, then the
>   property defaults to a system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you
>   should set the value for the normal state.

But I have also found `UIControlState.init()` being used, for example following line:

```
UIButton.setTitleColor(UIColor, for: UIControlState())
```

Was wondering how it differs, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`UIControlState.normal` is a specific control state representing the "normal" state.

`UIControlState()` is an "empty" control state with some undocumented default value.

It just so happens that both of these are backed with a raw value of `0`. So it seems that both represent the "normal" state.

But it is bad practice to rely on this. The defaults could change. It is much better to use the specific, clearly documented values provided.

Always use `UIControlState.normal` for the "normal" state. Never use `UIControlState()` since its value is undocumented and there is no guarantee it will always have the same underlying value as `UIControlState.normal`.

Comment: I don't understand why do people prefer `UIControl.State()` instead of just writing `.normal`.

Comment: I more prefer to use `[]`:
button.setTitleColor(.green, for: [])

Answer (score 2):

Just found in console, both `UIControlState()` and `.normal` are equal, so there is no difference